# Under what circumstances can the root component be unmounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a root component that initialises and hosts the entire application and that when simplified looks like

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // initialisation here
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // I expect this to never happen
    }

    render() {
        // the whole app is rendered here
    }
}
```

It's rendered on the page as simple as just (I do it just once, that script runs on page load and never is called again)

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, domElement);
```

What I have discovered recently is that sometimes (extremely rarely) the `App`'s `componentWillUnmount` is getting called.

Last time it happened on the mobile chrome 67, but also was observed on a desktop one as well.

I captured that event with a dummy `raven.captureMessage('application will unmount');` (where `raven` is a sentry client), so at this moment I don't have any more details yet.

But it is totally surprising to me: under what circumstances can the root component be unmounted by react? No JS touches the react-managed DOM, the last occurrence happened on a phone of a person I know and it's a regular chrome browser without any modifications.

I talked to the person - and they mentioned that the application visually look normal (but for obvious reasons it did not function properly - since I deinitialise things there).

Another odd moment is that I also log if `componentDidMount` happened more than once (via a module-scoped variable) for that component, and it was not called.

So to summarise: the `componentWillUnmount` was called, the DOM node has not been removed, the consecutive `componentDidMount` was not called (this sequence sounds unbelievable to me, but that's what I observed).

Another important thing: for the latest case it happened exactly after the chrome un-hibernated the tab (chrome puts a tab in hibernation when it is hibernated or when other tabs need ram/cpu).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: And you're not calling `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` anywhere directly, or indirectly through some sort of wrapping library?

Comment: @djfdev `grep` for `unmountComponentAtNode` shows it presents only in react itself and reactstrap library. In the latter case it's applied to the modal `div`. And I certainly don't call it directly - the `ReactDOM.render(<App />, domElement);` is literally the only place I have a reference to `App` at all.

Comment: @zerkms If you found the reason I'd really like to know it. I found that if you create a codesandbox when saving the code `componentWillUnmount()` of the root component is getting called. But that may be for several reasons how they handle the sandboxes and the emulated browser window.

Comment: @trixn given it's impossible to reproduce - debugging will take quite some time :-D I will add one thing at a time to the `sentry` log messages to get deeper. And yep, I'll keep this post updating

Comment: @zerkms Maybe you could throw an error that you catch to log a stack trace. Might help understanding who the misterious caller was.

Comment: @trixn yep, exactly my thoughts. It probably won't help though: react is heavily asynchronous these days, so the the actual cause of re-rendering or unmounting might be in another stacktrace. But still, it's the best I can see.

Answer (score 1):

One circumstance is when you render another component into the root container with `ReactDOM`:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const OtherComponent = () => <p>test</p>;

class App extends Component {    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('will unmount');
    }

    handleRenderOtherComponent = () => {
        ReactDOM.render(<OtherComponent />, rootElement);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleRenderOtherComponent}>
                remove root
            </button>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit 1vp8o058p3]

Comment: Upvoted for the idea, in my case though I only render it once (sorry for not mentioning it in the question, now fixed it)

Comment: Is this common in react app to render a new root component?  I am also wondering when componentWillUnmount in root component is called normally

Comment: @techguy2000 Most commonly a react app is a single page application and only has one root component that never gets unmounted. A component gets unmounted when the parent doesn't render it anymore. The root component has no parent that could unmount it. However it may be unmounted because of an unhandled error during render. There is no restriction that prevents you from rendering multiple root component on the same page. Those would be independent react applications running next to each other. Possibly some widget-like small components on an otherwise static page.